# Generate Positive Definite Matrix in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

In Julia, is there any function or way to generate a positive definite matrix of arbitrary size/dimensions? I know the package PSDMatrices can technically do this, but it returns an object that is not of the **matrix type**, so thus many functions do not have methods for it.

Comment: Just some random example, or does it have to satisfy some further properties? Take some random matrix `X` and return `A=X*X'`.

Comment: Backgorund of @LutzLehmann's answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Decomposition

Comment: Or if more control is wanted: create a diagonal matrix `D` with the desired spectrum, create a random square matrix `X`, apply QR decomposition `Q*R=X`, return `A=Q*D*Q'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you generate a `PSDMatrix m` with the PSDMatrices package, `Matrix(m)` will give you a matrix type.